# Unity3D. Colliders don't react to model

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**I use this code to move and rotate my object, but it moves through the walls. Yes, I have colliders on object and walls, but my object doesn't collide with these walls.**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class player_Control : MonoBehaviour {
    public float upspeed;
    public float downspeed;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    Transform myTrans;
    Vector3 myPos;
    Vector3 myRot;
    float angle;

    void Start() {
        myPos = transform.position;
        myRot = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
    }
    void FixedUpdate() { 
        angle = transform.eulerAngles.magnitude * Mathf.Deg2Rad;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) { // ROTATE RIGHT
            myRot.z -= rotationSpeed;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) { // ROTATE LEFT
            myRot.z += rotationSpeed;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)) { // UP
            myPos.y += (Mathf.Cos(-angle) * upspeed) * Time.deltaTime;
            myPos.x += (Mathf.Sin(-angle) * upspeed) * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)) { // DOWN
            myPos.y += (Mathf.Cos(-angle) * -downspeed) * Time.deltaTime;
            myPos.x += (Mathf.Sin(-angle) * -downspeed) * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        transform.position = myPos;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(myRot);

    }
}
```

Comment: In your objects' collider isTrigger is checked or not?

Comment: Do you have a `RigidBody` attached to your object?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue here is that you are bypassing the Unity's physics engine and altering the players position and rotation directly.
Unity's physics checks are built around usage of the Rigidbody component and has several specific functions for changing an objects position and rotation so that it collides correctly with other objects within the scene.
For your usage above I would look at the following two functions for changing position and rotation of your character:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html

Comment: It dont react to rotations, object movingg by x and y

Comment: @ЯрославСмирнов Can you please post your updated Code